# Find Array Class Object value - If exists: Move it as first array key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I'm looking for a php function that would find array class object value 'FIND_ME' and swap it as first array key if it exists.

Here is my current Array output :

```
Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ([id] => 1 [uid] => 52 [type] => A_TEST [title] => TITLE [value] => 1 ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ([id] => 2 [uid] => 52 [type] => TEST [title] => TITLE [value] => 1 )
        [2] => stdClass Object ([id] => 3 [uid] => 52 [type] => FIND_ME [title] => TITLE [value] => 1 )
    )
```

And here is the result I need :

```
Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ([id] => 3 [uid] => 52 [type] => FIND_ME [title] => TITLE [value] => 1 ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ([id] => 2 [uid] => 52 [type] => TEST [title] => TITLE [value] => 1 )
        [2] => stdClass Object ([id] => 1 [uid] => 52 [type] => A_TEST [title] => TITLE [value] => 1 )
    )
```

Result : Array[2] changed and became Array[0] because `type => FIND_ME` was found in the array.

Note: I don't care about the order of others keys.

Any idea?

EDIT: Okay I managed to find the key number of `type => FIND_ME` using foreach() :

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($value->type == 'FIND_ME') {
            $found = $key;
            break;
        }
    }
```

But how to swap it as first key of the array?

Comment: Does it matter what order the other elements are in after sorting?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't matter, I just want the value 'FIND_ME' gets the key [0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$found = $others = array();
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->type == 'FIND_ME') {
        $found[] = $value;
    }else{
        $others[] = $value;
    }
}
$array = array_merge($found,$others);
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfeclty. Think you ;)